# How to compare two dictionaries and update

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have two dictionaries 1.Primary, 2. Secondary

- Need to check first `field` of both dictionary
- If filed is same compare the title with primary and secondary
- if Primary have missing dictionary which is in dictionary add that to primary

Primary dictionary

```
{"Latest":[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Deveoper"
      },
      {
        "title": "C",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Tester"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Long Term"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]}
```

Secondary dictionary

```
[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      },
      {
        "title": "B",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "test",
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Tester",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

Expected out

```
{"Latest":[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Deveoper"
      },
      {
        "title": "C",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Tester"
      },
      {
        "title": "B",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "Long Term"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "role": "null"
      },
      {
        "title": "Tester",
        "paragraph": "null"
        "role": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]}
```

COde

```
 for i in primary['Latest']:
    for j in secondary:
        if i['field'] == j['field']:
            for a in i['values']:
                for b in j['values']:
                    if a['title'] == b['title']:
                        i['values'].append(b)
```

My code executes indefinitely

Comment: These look like JSON-objects, not dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are appending in `i['values']` while iterating on it, creating unexpected behaviour. You can fix it by iterating on a "frozen" list if `i['values']` like this:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

for i in primary['Latest']:
    for j in secondary:
        if i['field'] == j['field']:
            values = deepcopy(i['values'])
            for a in values:
                for b in j['values']:
                    if a['title'] == b['title']:
                        i['values'].append(b)
```

This resolves the "indefinitely" part, but doesn't quite work, here is the output:

```py
print(json.dumps(primary, indent=2))
{
  "Latest": [
    {
      "name": "Employee",
      "field": "employee",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "A",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "Deveoper"
        },
        {
          "title": "C",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "Tester"
        },
        {
          "title": "A",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Project",
      "field": "project",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "NEW_York",
          "paragraph": "null",
          "role": "Long Term"
        },
        {
          "title": "NEW_York",
          "paragraph": "test",
          "role": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Designation",
      "field": "designation",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "Developer",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I fixed it a little:

```py
for primary_elem in primary['Latest']:
    primary_titles = [value['title'] for value in primary_elem['values']]
    for secondary_elem in secondary:
        if secondary_elem['field'] == primary_elem['field']:
            for secondary_value in secondary_elem['values']:
                if secondary_value['title'] not in primary_titles:
                    primary_elem['values'].append(secondary_value)
```

Which gives

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(primary, indent=2))
{
  "Latest": [
    {
      "name": "Employee",
      "field": "employee",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "A",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "Deveoper"
        },
        {
          "title": "C",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "Tester"
        },
        {
          "title": "B",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Project",
      "field": "project",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "NEW_York",
          "paragraph": "null",
          "role": "Long Term"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Designation",
      "field": "designation",
      "values": [
        {
          "title": "Developer",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "null"
        },
        {
          "title": "Tester",
          "paragraph": null,
          "role": "null"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```